# Win 2003 server ignores css styles

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I deployed my webapp, created in asp.net, to testing server (win 2003 sp2, iis6). However, when I access the default page, no css styles are applied. There is only plain text, or formatting given in .aspx file.

I have my web form based on MasterPage.master. In this site head declaration, I have this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheets/Master.css" />
```

After displaying webpage source in client browser (FF 9), I found this line

```
<head><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../StyleSheets/Master.css" /><title>
```

Please, help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to give permission for "Everyone" to read StyleSheets folder

Answer (score 1):

The `~` in `href="~/StyleSheets/Master.css"` will only be processed when it's part of a server control.

So use page-relative or absolute addressing. I assume `"../StyleSheets/Master.css"` is not correct from the viewed page?

But it's probably an installation/configuration issue.

Comment: ad it's interesting, that declaration of path to css file is inside <head ... runat="server"> tag

Comment: Agreed. Can you check if you can access the stylesheet from your browser directly.

Comment: No, I can't. Apparently client doesn't have permission to browse webpage folders

Comment: Problem solved. I had to give permission for "Everyone" to read StyleSheets folder

Answer (score 1):

Are you working within a subfolder? If so, `~/` points to the parent of that folder unless you explicitly make the folder an application within IIS.

In other words, if `http://localhost/` points to `e:\your_site` and you are working out of `e:\your_site\your_app`, unless you convert `you_app` to an IIS application `~/` will assume that `e:\you_site` is root which is why the `../` is being put into the URL.

Comment: well, I have no idea, what are you talking about

Comment: Okay, first question, you've got the web address to your site, something like `http://www.example.com`. This address maps to the file system somewhere like `e:\your_site`, right? Is your "app" that you've deployed in a subfolder under `e:\your_site`, something like `e:\your_site\your_app`?

Comment: Problem solved. I had to give permission for "Everyone" to read StyleSheets folder